# How can I match the first instance of a pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex and input.

http://regex101.com/r/rY5xD2:

```
^(.+)\byo\b.*?(cut me:)
```

How can I just match the first instance of a pattern match?

-- Desired group match (text that I keep) --

```
Hi

yo keep this here

Keep this here
```

Comment: am sorry i don't understand u wan't to get the first sentence or first line from that paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
^(.+?)\byo\b(?:(?!cut me:|yo).)*cut me:
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/sB3kK5

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `^(((?!cut me:).)+)\byo\b.*?(cut me:)`

Idea is to not accept characters which are start of `cut me:`. But be careful because this approach may be very expensive for longer strings then `"cut me:"` because of backtracking.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/bW6eE0)

Comment: very cool, thanks for the reply! point taken regarding backtracking.